# My Prefix is Polish

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> My prefix is Polish
>   My postfix, just the opposite
>   My infix is easier to read
>   I can be anything you choose, but never, ever will I be a Tion.

What am I?

Comment: Is this question due a green checkmark now?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This figures out to be

> notation

My prefix is Polish

> [Polish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) notation, aka prefix notation.

My postfix, just the opposite

> [Postfix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) notation is also called Reverse Polish Notation.

My infix is easier to read

> [Infix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation) notation is easier to read for humans.

I can be anything you choose, but never, ever will I be a Tion.

> You can select your own notation, but this is *not a tion*.

Comment: I wanted to invert the whole thing, so please don't do that with the 4th spoiler block :-) (You are correct, of course)

Comment: Oops, fixed that. Maybe a T ion is ${^3}{H^+}$.

Comment: Oo, brilliant! Editing the question :-) (no cancel that, too contrived.)

Comment: (It's a brilliant clue, but since the whole point is pretending to *not* be brilliant, it would probably defeat the purpose)